# What is the definition of the following sentence ''His broad, windburned face bore a set"?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I was reading a fantasy novel by Terry Brooks, *The Sword of Shannara*, and in the first paragraph I came across the following sentence:

> His broad, windburned face bore a set, placid look, and only the wide
>   gray eyes revealed the restless energy that burned beneath the calm
>   exterior.

I know what the sentence means except for the part *"bore a set"* and I could not find anything so far on search-engines.
I am not a frequent reader of novels but when I read I really want to know exactly what every sentence means so thanks in advanced.

Comment: Here, "bore a set" means "had a fixed."

Comment: I think what's confusing you is "bore a set" is, by itself, incomplete. What's missing is "look". The guy's look was both *set* and *placid*. He looked stoic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are analyzing it wrong :-)

His face was broad and windburned, and the face bore a look that was set and placid.

The word "set" can be found in a dictionary, as a verb, noun and adjective. In this case, it is an adjective. There are various meanings, in this case: (of a person's expression) held for an unnatural long time without changing, typically as a reflection of determination.

Comment: thanks for the replay but what does "looking set" mean?

Comment: "looking set" never occurs in the discussion and would be a very strange construction.  What the original quote says is that he had a set and placid look.  That means what he looked like was very set and placid.